# OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-ec2, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc

pyodbc.drivers()
['PostgreSQL', 'MySQL', 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server']
```

I am trying to connect to a Database hosted on AWS EC2 using `pyodbc`. When attempting to connect, I receive a `Login timeout expired` error.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(
                        "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};" + "SERVER=.\x.x.x.x;"
                        "DATABASE=dbname;"
                        "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                     )

cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_28015/774124105.py in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 conn = pyodbc.connect(
      2                         "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};" + "SERVER=.\10.203.25.204;"
      3                         "DATABASE=KinsleyPortal;"
      4                         "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
      5                      )

OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: You probably need to supply login credentials.

Comment: @MattDMo Access is setup to use domain authentication (i.e., trusted security).

Comment: Is it `SERVER=.\x.x.x.x;`? Breaking that down: `.` means `localhost` and then `\x.x.x.x` means an instance named `x.x.x.x` on `localhost`. Have you tried just `SERVER=10.203.25.204;` instead?